# How can I make a hook execute after every step with a particular tag?

Tags: java, tags, cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to set up a after step hook that runs only after assertion steps (those that I tagged with @Then tag).
Is that even possible?
I'm trying

```
    @AfterStep(value = "@Then")
public void afterStep(Scenario scenario) {
    try {
        takeScreenshot(scenario);
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException ignore){
    }
}
```

But then it only runs if the scenario is tagged with @Then, it does not look into the steps tags.
Any help will be welcomed!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fear that this is not possible out of the box.

Cucumber doesn't provide a clear API to access the current running step in the @BeforeStep/@AfterStep hooks.

In general, I see 2 possible options for how you can achieve the desired goal (w/o using reflection on cucumber objects, the state of which cannot be guaranteed):

- The easiest one is to take screenshots in the step implementation. You likely have a driver passing around in your steps, scenario can also be moved to some shared context, so you can create a fancy method for screenshotting. This option is easy to implement, but it will result in minor, but still code duplication. Smth like:

```
    public void stepImpl() {
        try {
            // some step logic
            driver.....
        } finally {
            takeScreenshot(driver, context.getScenario());
        }
    }
```

- You can try to use [aspectj](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj). It may be a bit complex to setup, but with aspectj (and AOP in general) you can create advice that can be applied only to those methods, that are annotated with cucumber's @Then annotation. But in this case, you also need to store your driver and scenario in some shared context to be able to use it in your aspect. Smth like:

```
    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
    
    @Aspect
    public class ScreenshottingAspect {
    
        @Pointcut("execution(* your.package..*(..)) && @annotation(io.cucumber.java.en.Then)")
        public void methodExecution() {
        }
    
        @Around("methodExecution()")
        public Object captureScreenshot(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            try {
                return joinPoint.proceed();
            } finally {
                takeScreenshot(context.getDriver(), context.getScenario());
            }
        }
    
    }
```